Deleting an item permanently before and reloading the page
How to delete a notification permanently.
import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef } from 'react';
import { IoMdNotificationsOutline } from "react-icons/io";
import './notif.css';
import { getDocs, collection } from "firebase/firestore";
import { database } from "../config/firebase";
import { MdCancel } from "react-icons/md";

const NotificationComponent = () => {
  const [productList, setProductList] = useState([]);
  const productCollectionRef = collection(database, "singleProduct");

  async function getProductList() {
    try {
      const data = await getDocs(productCollectionRef);
      const filteredData = data.docs.map((doc) => ({
        ...doc.data(),
        id: doc.id
      }));
      setProductList(filteredData.reverse());
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getProductList();
  }, []);

  const [showNotifications, setShowNotifications] = useState(false);
  const [notifications, setNotifications] = useState([]);

  const [currentDate, setCurrentDate] = useState(new Date());
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);
  const currentDateRef = useRef(currentDate);

  useEffect(() => {
    currentDateRef.current = currentDate; // Update currentDateRef when currentDate changes
  }, [currentDate]);

  const toggleNotifications = () => {
    setShowNotifications(!showNotifications);
    if (showNotifications) {
      setCounter(0); // Reset the counter if showNotifications is true
    }
  };

  function isWithinOneWeek(date) {
    const targetDate = new Date(date);
    const checkWeekAhead = new Date();
    checkWeekAhead.setDate(checkWeekAhead.getDate() + 7);

    return Math.abs(targetDate.getTime() - checkWeekAhead.getTime()) <= 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const timer = setInterval(() => {
      setCurrentDate(new Date());
    }, 1000);

    return () => clearInterval(timer);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    const newNotifications = [];
    productList.forEach(product => {
      if (isWithinOneWeek(new Date(product.expirationDate.seconds * 1000))) {
        newNotifications.push({
          id: product.id,
          message: (
            <div className='notificationMessage'>
              <p>The Product: {product.productName} will be expired in one week</p>
              <p>Product Identifier: {product.uniqueIdentifier}{product.serialNum}</p>
              <p> {new Date(product.expirationDate.seconds * 1000).toLocaleDateString()}</p>
            </div>
          )
        });
      } else if (currentDateRef.current >= new Date(product.expirationDate.seconds * 1000)) {
        newNotifications.push({
          id: product.id,
          message: (
            <div className='notificationMessage'>
              <p>The Product: {product.productName} is expired.</p>
              <p>Product Identifier: {product.uniqueIdentifier}{product.serialNum}</p>
              <p> {new Date(product.expirationDate.seconds * 1000).toLocaleDateString()}</p>
            </div>
          )
        });
      }
    });
    setNotifications(newNotifications);
    setCounter(newNotifications.length);
    console.log(newNotifications);
  }, [productList]);

  // Function to delete a specific notification
  const handleDelete = (id) => {
    const updatedNotifications = notifications.filter(notification => notification.id !== id);
    setNotifications(updatedNotifications);
    setCounter(updatedNotifications.length);
    console.log(updatedNotifications);
  };

  return (
    <div className="notification-component">
      <div><h1>{currentDate.toLocaleDateString()}</h1></div>
      <div className="notification-icon" onClick={toggleNotifications}>
        <IoMdNotificationsOutline className='icon' />
        {showNotifications ? null : counter > 0 && (
          <span className="notification-counter">
            {counter}
          </span>
        )}
      </div>
      {showNotifications && (
        <div className="notification-list">
          <h3>Notifications</h3>
          <ul>
            {notifications.map(notification => (
              <li key={notification.id}>
                {notification.message}
                <span className='deleteNotif' onClick={() => handleDelete(notification.id)}>
                  <MdCancel />
                </span>
              </li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default NotificationComponent;


After I reload the page it constantly reappears. I want it to delete it on the page. For example there are 6 notifications newNotifications array is [6], I delete a specific notification and after I console.log it, the array became [5]. but after I reload the page, the newNotification array became [6] again. I want it so that it will not reappear in the page. I am new to web design.

We need to distinguish between frontend and backend here. Your React application is your frontend and Firestore is your backend.
What you are doing is removing a notification from React, this will work as long as the application is running, but when you refresh the page the React application will be "restarted", and all state changes made solely to React will be lost. No state in React can be persisted during refresh.
If you want to persist a state change you need to store it in the backend, in this case your Firestore database. There are several ways to do this depending on your needs, but the easiest way is probably to add a field to the product that tells whether the notification has been removed.

Is it okay to use local storage or cookies for this problem?

Sure, if it fits your needs. But I as user would find it weird if I saw two different things in two different browsers.
